# How to create a model with dynamic amount of the nested items TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of workouts. Each workout has nested exercises, e.g:
Workout name: "Day 1"
Exercises: push-ups, squats, etc.

Users should be able to create new exercises and delete those they don't need.
So, I want to create a Workout model that will include these exercises. The problem is you never know how many of these exercises will be there.

I think I just don't fully understand the models. Could you advise, please?
How the workout model should look like?

My target is that after the user will add a new Workout with exercises I will be able to do something like:

```
export interface Workout {
  name: string,
  exercises: [ Exercise1, Exercise2, Exercise3, ... ]
}

export interface Exercise {
  name: string,
  status: boolean
}
```

```
newWorkout: Workout = {name: "Day 1", exercises: [ {name: "push-ups", completed: true}, {name: "squats", completed: false} ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding exercises as an array of Exercise in Workout should allow you to do that:

```
export interface Workout {
  name: string,
  exercises: Exercise[]
}

export interface Exercise {
  name: string,
  status: boolean
}
```

But please clarify what you mean by "The problem is you never know how many of these exercises will be there.". What is the problem you actually encountered / what is your question?

Comment: After the Workout will be created users can dynamically add/remove exercises related to this Workout. And I thought if I will hardcode a number of exercises in the Workout model then I'll have an issue. So what you proposed makes sense. I am new to this concept so I might not understand how it works fully yet